# Was scene with Dick Smothers early in film with hooker in theatrical release?

Tags: alternate-version, casino

I just now saw a scene I do not recall seeing before in Casino -- Dick Smothers plays "Senator" and he eventually denies Rothstein a license but early in the film they show how the casino takes care of influential locals and the Senator is shown with a tall, blonde hooker -- they also show the Japanese whale in this same sequence of scenes which I do remember but while I remember Smothers later, these early scenes I think must not be present in any version of Casino that I have previously watched. Am I right?